# Ends of verbs after words "which", "that" & "who"

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

If in such construction:

```
Noun -> any of the words (which || that || who) -> verb.
```

the noun is singular, should the verb have "-s" end?

For example:

> The girl who **love(*s*)** kittens.

Comment: In *any* construction, singular noun **will** have '-s' end! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The girl who love(s) kittens.

The construction is called a *relative clause*, and "**who**" here is a relative pronoun.

If the clause is in the present tense, and has a third-person singular subject, then yes, the [verb should have the suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_verbs#Third_person_singular_present) **(e)s**.

Wikipedia says the clause also should be in the [Indicative Mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realis_mood).

Note that this only works for third-person subjects:

> You, who **love** kittens, come here and see a new kitten clip I've just found on YouTube! (a bit high-hat, but anyway: the second-person **you** licenses the use of **love**, not **loves**)
>   We, who **love** kittens, gather in this quiet park every Saturday. (first-person subject **we** --> **love**, not **loves**)

An example from a poem: the poet addresses the Moon (second-person: **you**) and thus uses **rise**, not **rises** in the relative clause starting with the relative pronoun "*that*":

> Enormous moon, that **rise** behind these hills
>   Heavy and yellow in a sky unstarred
>   And pale, your girth by purple fillets barred
>   Of drifting cloud, that as the cool sky fills
>   With planets and the brighter stars, distills
>   To thinnest vapor and floats valley-ward,—
>   **You** flood with radiance all this cluttered yard,
>   The sagging fence, the chipping window sills.

The author of one poetic blog [explains this in this way](http://zackrogow.blogspot.ru/2013/04/writers-i-cant-stop-reading-part-6-edna.html):

> Interesting that she uses "**rise**" for the moon in line 1 and not "**rises**." I think she is addressing the moon—"**you** that rise."

At the same time, she uses "*sky fill**s***" and "*cloud ...  distill**s***". (these are third-person subjects)

---

Reference:

- [English Verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_verbs): *[third person singular present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_verbs#Third_person_singular_present)* - Wikipedia
- [Some interesing bits on the history of verbal suffixes](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/22463/48335) - ELU

Comment: In other words, you conjugate exactly as you would for related simple declarative sentence— "The girl loves kittens."

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - yes, indeed. (0: I got carried away a bit.